# which html tags can use class attribute example: <i class="myclass">text inside</i>?

Tags: xhtml, html

Which HTML tags can use the `class` attribute?

(In which standards — e.g. HTML/XHTML/HTML5 etc. — and in which browsers.)

For example, is the following legal or not?

```
<i class="myclass">text inside</i>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using `<em>text inside</em>` rather than `<i>` as it is more semantically correct.

Comment: @AdamBeizsley-Pycroft It's wrong anyway. It is possible to have text formatted as italics without meaning "this has emphasis".

Comment: @Quentin `<i>` tags are presentational and their use goes completely against the accepted wisdom of separating content from presentation.

Comment: “<i> tags are presentational and their use goes completely against the accepted wisdom of separating content from presentation” — this has changed in HTML5, `<i>` tags have meaning there: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-i-element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HTML 4, the [`class` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class) can be used in [all elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html) except but [`BASE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE), [`BASEFONT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-BASEFONT), [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-HEAD), [`HTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-HTML), [`META`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-META), [`PARAM`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-PARAM), [`SCRIPT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT), [`STYLE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#edef-STYLE), and [`TITLE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-TITLE) (see [index of attributes in the HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html)). And since XHTML 1.0 is (briefly) just HTML 4 with XML syntax, this does also apply to XHTML 1.0.

Comment: @faileN — you seem to have fallen into the trap of assuming that the class attribute exists for no reason other than to allow CSS to be applied. That isn't the case.

Comment: It is probably worth pointing out that http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html has a summary of which elements each attribute in HTML 4.01 apply to.

Answer (score 3):

In HTML5, the class attribute, along with the accesskey, contenteditable, contextmenu, dir, draggable, hidden, id, lang, spellcheck, style, tabindex and title attributes, 
is valid on all elements. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#global-attributes

Comment: That's also in the [Working Draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#classes): “Every HTML element may have a class  attribute specified.”

Answer (score 1):

Well I am pretty sure, that each and every tag may contain the class-attribute (correct me, if I am wrong).

EDIT

Okay Gumbo stated the tags, that a not allowed to use the class-attribute for good reason (see my comment at his answer). Thank you.